# Manifold with the same dimension as $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

I am studying manifolds at a basic level, and I was wondering if, when a set has the same dimension as the space where it is defined (take, for instance, $\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1 \}$), it neccesarily needs to be open to be a manifold. For example, I know that the previous example is it, but if one replaces $<$ by $\leq$, then it is closed and I know it is not a manifold. In this case, since the dimension of both $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the space in which is embedded) and the disc of radius $1$ are the same ($3$), is the fact that one is open and the other not what makes the difference? I ask this because for a 2-dimensional set in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it can be closed and still be a manifold. Take for example $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.

Comment: Every point of your subset of $\Bbb R^n$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic (or diffeomorphic) to an (open) $n$-dimensional ball. What is the union of all these neighborhoods?

Comment: By the way, it is not exactly this question, but is a paraboloid a manifold? I think it is since the function that defines it has always non-null gradient.

Comment: Yes! You might find some of my YouTube lectures on the introduction to manifolds in $\Bbb R^n$ (among other things) helpful.  See the link in my profile.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that if a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold then that subset must be open. This is a deep theorem of algebraic topology, known as the [Invariance of Domain Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

Comment: Is this an iff? This is, if it is open, given the conditions I mentioned above, can I conclude it is a manifold?

Comment: @DanielC. For open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, you have an obvious global chart.

Comment: I am still not familiarised with charts

Comment: A chart is a continuous bijection onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ whose inverse is continuous. If $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, then the identity map from $U$ to itself is a chart. So yes, an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is a manifold; this is almost immediate from the definitions, in contrast to the deep mathematics underlying the invariance of domain theorem.